# XML code for textview to view in the end of page of a scroll View

Tags: java, android, xml

In my Android app.. I need my textview..( textview about contact us) so this textview has to be at the end of the page of the scroll view.. it should be above the scrollview.. I did code like this but what happening is textview is filling from the centre  to the bottom..

I am giving my code below.. I used align_parentbottom ... but the text is at the centre and the rest portion is filling till the bottom with the background color..

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">"
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Current Challenge"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="PDNo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Your Current Challenge : "
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Prediction for your Current Challenge will be displayed here..." />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/title_border"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Contact us :"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

         />

    </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Show the complete xml.

Comment: post screen shot for better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/orange">

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Current Challenge"
            android:textSize="18dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="PDNo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Your Current Challenge : "
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="Prediction for your Current Challenge will be displayed here..." /> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:text="Contact us :"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"` from textView5

Comment: It should be not because in ScrollView the height of other layout must be wrap_content. And if you use match_parent its useless.

Comment: agree. Changed my answer